# Nodejs (2 ** 64) - (2 ** 5) === (2 ** 64) ? Why

Tags: javascript, node.js

OK something weird happened to me I did the following equality comparison in `Nodejs` and surprisingly it replied with `true`.

```js
(2 ** 64) - 1000 === (2 ** 64) // true
```

Why is that?

```sh
> for (let i = 0; i<=20; i++)
... console.log(i, (2 ** 64) - (2 ** i) === (2 ** 64))
0 true
1 true
2 true
3 true
4 true
5 true
6 true
7 true
8 true
9 true
10 true
11 false
12 false
13 false
14 false
15 false
16 false
17 false
18 false
19 false
20 false
```

Comment: In addition to the duplicate link, we sort of would expect this, since `2^64` is a very large number, and floating point arithmetic is not exact anyway.

Comment: This is the biggest number you can accurately represent: 9007199254740992. 2 ** 53

Comment: Try in your console 2 ** 53, 2 ** 53 + 1, 2 ** 53 - 1

Comment: If you want to do math on bigger numbers, you'll have to use a library specifically for big numbers

Comment: thanks @TKoL so nodejs computes 2 ** (bigger than 53) but can't do a comparison on it?

Comment: In this case it looks like its computing it correctly, but I wouldn't even rely on it to compute the correct value for bigger values than 53 in general. And yes, any additional computations on the same value are very unlikely to come out correct.